# Find an unbiased estimator for $\ln(1-p)$ from a sample of size one from Bernoulli$(p)$

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

I've found an interesting task on the net and was not able to solve it.
We have a sample of one element from $Bern(p)$.

The goal is to find a unique unbiased estimator for $ln(1-p)$ OR to prove that it does not exist.

So far, I've tried to find the function which should be placed in the equation of expectation for $f(X_1)$, but nothing comes to mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose when your observation is $1$ you estimate $a$ and when your observation is $0$ you estimate $b$.  Then the expected value of your estimate is $pa+(1-p)b$ and this is at least $\min(a,b)$.

But for $p \gt 1 - e^{\min(a,b)}$ you will have $\ln(1-p) \lt \min(a,b)$ and so at least for those $p$ the estimator will be biased for any particular $a$ and $b$

Comment: I have the impression that one should first point out that we must have $\min(a,b)<0$ (since we require $pa+(1-p)b = \ln (1-p)<0$, in order for your approach to be complete.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos: It does not matter for my answer: $e^{\min(a,b)} \gt 0$ so there will be potential values of $p$ greater than  $1 - e^{\min(a,b)}$, so long as $a$ and $b$ are finite: if they were both positive then the estimator would be biased for all possible $p$.  But your point is essentially correct in that $\ln(1-p)$ will be non-positive when $0 \le p \lt 1$

Answer (score 0):

I will give a different answer from Henry's. My answer will tell you that the only functions of $p$ that you can estimate with no bias using one observation from $Bern(p)$ are linear functions of $p$.

If there exists an unbiased estimator $T(X)$ of $f(p)$ (where $f$ is any function) then $E(T(X))=f(p)$ implies $T(1)p+T(0)(1-p)=f(p)$ for all $p\in(0,1)$.

The left side is linear in $p$ since $T(.)$ does not have $p$ in its expression, being a statistic. Thus $f$ has to be linear. This shows $\log(1-p)$ cannot be estimated without bias.

Comment: Thus, one can also estimate $13p+42$...